# Customizing <ImageInput> Component to add Profile Image

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

We are using react-admin for our application. 
For our sign-up page, we have an option to pick a profile image. (This is using material-UI)
How can we customize the InputImage component as per UI design?

[The Avatar design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEJaD.png)

How do we extend and change the UI for ImageInput?
If we cannot extend, do we have an API to creating our own Input Components?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look here: "Writing Your Own Input Component" https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html